# Enable Select Option on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to add a div for the select option and disable it within the select dropdown.

This I have working, with a delete button, however I want to re-enable the select option if the delete button is pressed - this is what I have so far been unable to do.

Can anyone kindly assist?

jQuery solution preferred but JavaScript solution also good.  Open to solutions such as hide/show instead of disable/enable.

```js
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
  $('#here').append('<div>' + $(this).val() + '<button>DELETE</button> </div>');
  $('option:selected', this).attr('disabled', true);
});

$("div").on("click", "button", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('select').find($('option:selected', this)).attr('disabled', false);
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 15px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option>Please select one</option>
    <option>Volvooooo</option>
    <option>Saaaaaab</option>
    <option>Mercedeeeeeeees</option>
    <option>Audiiiiiii</option>
  </select>

<div id="here">Nothing selected yet</div>
```

Note that as far as I am aware, this is not a duplicate question - and the question that it has been marked as a duplicate of most certainly does not relate to my question, which is specifically about removing disabled property on button click.  Please do not close my question unless you actually find a proper duplicate (which I couldn't with nearly two hours of searching SO).

Comment: What do you think `this` is in the click event handler?

Comment: @Musa - the delete button?

Comment: But you use it to find a option descendants here `$('option:selected', this)` which it does not have and a value here `$(this).val()` which it does not have

Comment: Hi, I made a working sample for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/rbLpp1fu/10/

Comment: Thanks ever so much @Repo - a massive help

Comment: Not sure why you've used `e.preventDefault();` `<button type="button"` shouldn't need that.

Comment: It's not overly clear what you need (how can an option be re-enabled if it's not selectable and the user has changed the select to something else, sounds like bad UX), but I made a quick experiment here: https://jsfiddle.net/3m4d9n7s/
You should be using `.prop` as opposed to `.attr`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the boolean value to false instead of true.

```js
  $('option:selected', this).attr('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I Just added a line here so after clicking delete button, option having val 0 got change. What you should do is to change your html code and add val.

Here is the html code.

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Please select one</option>
    <option value="1">Volvooooo</option>
    <option value="2">Saaaaaab</option>
    <option value="3">Mercedeeeeeeees</option>
    <option value="4">Audiiiiiii</option>
  </select>

<div id="here">Nothing selected yet</div>
```

And here is the JS code,

```
$('#mySelect').on('change', function (e){
   if($('#mySelect>option:selected').val() != "0"){
     $('#here').append('<div>' + $('#mySelect>option:selected').text() + '<button class="deleteButton" value="' + $(this).val() + '">DELETE</button> </div>');
     $('#mySelect>option:selected').attr('disabled', true);
   }    
 });  
 
 $("div").on("click", ".deleteButton", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#mySelect').val('0').trigger('change');
   $('#mySelect>option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').attr('disabled', false);
   $(this).parent().remove();
 });
```